# Matplotlib: How to change size of individual 3d subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

I have the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(131)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132)
ax3 = plt.subplot(133, projection="3d")

x = np.array([14, 74, 43, 47, 54, 66, 74, 89, 12, 44, 1, 24, 3, 4, 5, 95, 8, 7, 68, 5, 89])

y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 5, 2])

z = np.array([9, 6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2])

ax1.scatter(x, np.zeros(x.size))
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter3D(x, y, z)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which produces the plot shown below. How can I change the size of the 3d plot to make it fill up the empty space better? I've tried to work with `figsize=` and `height_ratios=[1, 1, 3]` but could not make it work.

[image]